# I have code to write to the console from a stored procedure, however I'd like to write to a text file / Excel

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, console-application, writetofile

I have the below code that writes to the console app from a stored procedure, however I would like to know how to write to a a text file / Excel and there after send in an e-mail.

```
private static void ListEnrollments() **Function Name**
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("**My connection String removed**"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Enrollments", conn))
        {               
            // Opens the database     
            conn.Open();

            // Call the stored procedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 

            // read data returned from the stored procedure
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Select the column from the returned dataset 
                String Message = reader.GetString("Message");

                // Write to the console 
                Console.WriteLine($"{Message}");
            }

            conn.Close();
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the below code and it seems to write to a test file, is this the best preferred way?

```
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    FileStream ostrm;//Provides a stream, allows to read and write
                    StreamWriter writer;//write characters to the stream
                    TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;//writes a series of characters = displays output
                    try
                    {
                        ostrm = new FileStream("./EnrollmentsTest.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);//Initialises a new Instance of the FilesStream Class with Path and the allows it to write
                        writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);//Writes to the FileStream Class
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Cannot open Redirect.txt for writing");
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        return;
                    }
```